# Using psql with string variable that has two periods

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, psql

```
psql -d mydb -U me -h localhost -f db_log.sql -v db_user_string='Me' -v version="1.7.3"
```

into the script

```
begin;

create table db_log (
    db_owner varchar(255) not null, 
    db_user varchar(255) not null, 
    version varchar(255) not null, 
    created timestamp, 
    id serial primary key
);

insert into db_log (db_owner, db_user, version, created) 
    VALUES (current_user, :db_user_string, :version, current_timestamp);

commit;
```

gives...

```
psql:db_log.sql:10: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ".3"
```

Any ideas?

I am using 9.3.0

Comment: Why do you use `varchar(255)`?  Why not `varchar(256)`, or, even better, unlimited `varchar` or`text`?

Answer (score 2):

Try an extra layer of quotes around your variables:

```
psql -d mydb -U me -h localhost -f db_log.sql -v db_user_string="'Me'" -v version="'1.7.3'"
```